# EF6 calling include after asenumerable

Tags: c#, .net, include, entity-framework-6, iqueryable

I have an entity with a few ordinary 1 to many relationships and one collection with implicit 1 to many relationship without any relationship defined.

What I'm trying to do is to make it work together like:

```
IQueryable<Employee> leftJoin =
            _dbContext.EmployeeList
                .GroupJoin(
                    inner: _dbContext.ContactList.Where(x => x.TableType == TableType.Employee),
                    outerKeySelector: employee => employee.EmployeeId,
                    innerKeySelector: contact => contact.TableId,
                    resultSelector: (employee, contacts) => new { employee, contacts = contacts.DefaultIfEmpty() }
                )
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x =>
                {
                    x.employee.ContactList = x.contacts;
                    return x.employee;
                })
                .AsQueryable()
                .Include(x => x.EmployeeRoleMapList);
```

The main hassle is I need to somehow init Employee.ContactList from joined set, within IQuerable it's not possible, I'm made to cast it to the IEnumerable but after that ordinary include doesn't work which is logical as well. Is there some workaround or some different way I could use to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you should use `_dbContext.ContactList.Where(x => x.TableType == TableType.Employee).ToList()` to force ContactList evaluation?

Comment: It's not what I would like but it's possible, but what to do next with loaded set?

Comment: Well, you stated that: "I need to somehow init Employee.ContactList from joined set", I assumed you had a problem with empty ContactList, as without .ToList() it is not eagerly evaluated. Could you explain a little more what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Let's say it's a repository/service method Get(). In the sample code init works well as expected, I need to somehow return back IQueryable<Employee> for being able to work with this contract from the client code(using include/where/etc.) but with joined alredy ContactList set within the query. It looks impossible, but maybe there's a workaround.

Comment: I can't use include for ContactList because there's no relationship defined. But I need to include this child collection and other ordinary collections. Of course I could join them all instead of using include and it might work but it's the last resort.

Comment: Since you are using projection, I don't think it's possible even if you move it before `AsEnumerable()` (e.g. _dbContext.EmployeeList.Include(...)`).

Comment: I supposed so. It doesn't work either even if to move it before, that is the different and known issue.